# how to join two tables when matching entry doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble writing this SQL Query.

Basically, I have the following tables;

`received_flight_files_table & uploaded_flight_files_table`

And the following fields;

`Processing_Month, IATA_Code, Airline, Received_Date, Uploaded_Date`

I would like the query to produce something like the first attached screenshot.

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

The 2 date fields you can see are from different tables though. 
The join can be done on the IATA_Code and Airline fields as both of these values should be the same in both tables.

Here are 2 examples of statements I have written which aren't quite right;

```
SELECT DISTINCT received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month, received_flight_files_table.IATA_Code, received_flight_files_table.Airline, received_flight_files_table.Received_Date, uploaded_flight_files_table.Uploaded_Date, published_flight_table.Published_Date
FROM ((received_flight_files_table 
INNER JOIN uploaded_flight_files_table ON uploaded_flight_files_table.Processing_Month=received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month) 
INNER JOIN published_flight_table ON published_flight_table.Published_Month=received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month
WHERE received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month = [enter MMMYY];`   

SELECT DISTINCT received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month, received_flight_files_table.IATA_Code, received_flight_files_table.Airline, received_flight_files_table.Received_Date, uploaded_flight_files_table.Uploaded_Date
FROM (((received_flight_files_table 
INNER JOIN uploaded_flight_files_table ON uploaded_flight_files_table.Processing_Month=received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month
INNER JOIN uploaded_flight_files_table ON uploaded_flight_files_table.IATA_Code=received_flight_files_table.IATA_Code
INNER JOIN uploaded_flight_files_table ON uploaded_flight_files_table.Airline=received_flight_files_table.Airline)))
WHERE (received_flight_files_table.Processing_Month = [enter MMMYY];
```

There should sometimes be some blanks in the Uploaded_Date field as for example - in one table I might have received the files but not yet uploaded them.

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with your expected output.

Comment: Are you after a LEFT JOIN (x2) so you get an entry when there isn't a match? Do you need the distinct? IS the date really in MMMYY format or a proper syntax and what is the type of Processing_Month?

Comment: I think an afternoon with any (recent-ish) basic, introductory book or tutorial would prove instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join